# How to add value to SerializableDictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to add value to `AdditionalProperties` of `AdaptiveCard` which is `SerializableDictionary<string, object>`. Below is the code I'm trying.

```
var paths = new[] { ".", "Resources", "ListCard.json" };
var listCardJson = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(paths));

AdaptiveCard card = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(listCardJson).Card;
var properties = card.AdditionalProperties;

var obj = new AdaptiveTextBlock()
{
     Text = "No tasks found."
};

properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("items", obj));
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter of Dictionary<string,object>.Add<string,object>

Any solution?

Comment: I would assume the syntax should be identical to a normal dictionary `properties.Add("items", obj);`

Comment: I rolled back your edit, because it invalidates an existing answer below (please verify that it solves the issue in your current question). If you have further issues, please post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SerializableDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server-essentials/gg496181(v=msdn.10)) derives from [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0), and inherits the `Add` method from it.

As you can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.add?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_Add__0__1_), it requires **separate arguments** for the key and value:

> public void Add (TKey key, TValue value);

Therefore you need to change:

```
properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("items", obj));
```

To:

```
properties.Add("items", obj);
```

Comment: Thanks @wohlstad for the solution for the previous question. I realized the solution after posting the question so I have updated the question.